# Use ConditionExpression to only update the status, if the current status !== 'FINISH'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a `ConditionExpression` to only update the `status` in my DynamoDB table `item`. That's how I'm doing:

```
  dynamo.update({
    TableName,
    Key,
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #status = :status',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#status': 'status'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':lastStatus': 'FINISH',
      ':status': 'PROCESSING'
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'not(contains(:lastStatus, :status))',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    console.log(data)
  })
```

But it's not working. the status is updating to 'PROCESSING', even if is 'FINISH'.

Comment: This question could use a little more clarity. Are you saying you only want to update the value of `status` to 'PROCESSING' if `status` is not currently equal to 'FINISH'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ConditionExpression` looks like it will always yield true. From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html), the `contain` function takes a path and an operand value. If the path is a string, it returns true when that string contains the operand value as a substring; if the path is a set, it returns true when that set contains the operand value as one of its elements.

You are substituting two expression values into your function, so it will always evaluate as `contain('FINISH', 'PROCESSING')`, which will never be true. The `not` wrapped around it makes it always true, so the condition is always met.

If you are just wanting not to update when the status is already 'PROCESSING', you might have luck with a `ConditionExpression` like `'#status <> :lastStatus'`. This should only return true when the `status` attribute does not equal a value of 'PROCESSING'.